# Can't get "owner" and "updated_time" on events since last week v2.12

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I retrieve Facebook events to feed an events website.

Since last week (Thursday April 12th I think), some things seem to have changed.

I used to query a user for her events like this :

```
$fb->get('/me/events?limit=500&since=now&fields=picture,name,description,cover,owner,end_time,start_time,updated_time,timezone,interested_count,place,type', $me->Get('token'));
```

If I continue using this request, I only receive one event. If I remove the "owner" and "updated_time", I receive the list of events .

Of course, I need these data.

I've tried to only retrieve the event ID and then do a GET on the '/'.$event['id'] but this returns all the values except "owner" and "updated_time".

Any idea ?

Thank you.

Comment: did you read the changelog and the breaking changes?

Comment: I did but I haven't found any info about "owner" and "updated_time". I'd appreciate if you had a link to that specific information.

Comment: the same is valid for the field is_canceled. at the moment to access this fields you need the owner access token (whether its a user or a page). the breaking changes log is here [link]https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes[/link] but is doesn't mention anything about this fields